# Django Model Not being updated

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to take a list of teams from my mlb_teams table, and find every combination of teams vs teams however when i run the code below im not getting any updates into the mlb_games tables.

```
values = mlb_teams.objects.all().values_list("long_name")
values = itertools.combinations(values, 2)
for value in list(values):
    first_team = value[0][0]
    second_team = value[1][0]
    add_teams = mlb_games(team_a=first_team,team_b=second_team)
    add_teams.save()
```

Comment: where's the rest? what is `mlb_games`? what is `add_teams`?

Comment: What do your models look like? Are you getting any errors, or is it just not saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be an issue with the way you are looping through your values. Maybe try something like this.

```
games = itertools.combinations(teams, 2)

for a, b in games:
    game = mlb_games(team_a=a, team_b=b)
    game.save()
```